# Tooltip is displayed for dialog box but not for child window

Tags: winapi, mfc, tooltip

I'm working on an MFC project (old technology, I know).

In my dialog-box class (derived from `CDialog`) I have:

```
CToolTipCtrl m_cToolTipCtrl;
CWnd         m_cImageWindow;
```

In the class `OnInitDialog` function I do:

```
m_cToolTipCtrl.Create(this);
m_cImageWindow.CreateEx(...);
m_cToolTipCtrl.AddTool(this,_T("Parent"));
m_cToolTipCtrl.AddTool(&m_cImageWindow,_T("Child"));
```

In the class `PreTranslateMessage` function I do:

```
m_cToolTipCtrl.RelayEvent(pMsg);
```

When I run the project, the `"Parent"` tooltip is displayed whenever I hover within the parent window, but the `"Child"` tooltip is not displayed whenever I hover within the child window.

I have originally tried this without the `"Parent"` tooltip and it didn't work, so it is obviously not a matter of the `"Parent"` tooltip masking the `"Child"` tooltip.

I think that events are relayed only to the parent window, but I'm not really sure how to tackle this problem.

Putting a breakpoint in the `PreTranslateMessage` function is useless, since it stops eminently on every event that the application receives. How can I investigate this problem?

Comment: May be you need to make your dialog respond to such type of events. Some bibliography: http://simplesamples.info/mfc/IdleProcessing.aspx

Comment: @sergiol: OK, but how would this explain the fact that my dialog box DOES respond to "tooltip events" in some cases? Thanks.

Comment: It is not nitid to me what cases the tooltip displayed.

Comment: And you can have conditional breakpoints or tracepoints.

Comment: @sergiol: Of course, but what condition do I use in order to catch the event which is supposed to trigger a tooltip for the child window?

Comment: I'm curios. Why not use the framework tips. EnableToolTips( ) and handle the TTN_NEEDTEXT message?

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer:

Simply add the `SS_NOTIFY` flag to the child window style when creating it.

For example:

```
m_cImageWindow.CreateEx(0,WC_STATIC,NULL,WS_CHILD|SS_NOTIFY,{0,0,0,0},this,0);
```

Comment: Oh! MFC always have such annoying details!

Comment: @sergiol: Honestly, this technology is so twisted! I just found out that adding `SS_NOTIFY` to the child window has masked the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message to the parent window. Absolutely unbelievable!!! Now struggling with flickering in the `OnPaint` function (which I swear was not a problem up until a few weeks). I'm starting to regret not doing it in WPF.

Comment: Just as a comment: This flags have nothing to do with MFC. It is just only Windows UI...

Comment: You have the wrong mindset. MFC is **harder** than plain Windows API programming. It makes those developers more efficient, that know both platforms. It doesn't appear that you know the Windows API well enough, and this answer never explains, what the core issue is (presumably the dialog manager running its own modal message loop, bypassing the user-provided `PreTranslateMessage` implementation). Posting a solution without a rationale is only going to promote [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).